# Client usually disconnected from server after a few dozen minutes

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sockets

I've created a server-client communicate program in .NET (c# or vb.net) using TCPListener - Socket on port 8080. In simple words, the program work like a chat software, client connect to server, and both wait for message from each other and then process it.

To retrieve packet from client, i using are using a "While" method like this :

```
While true

Dim Buffer(4096) As Byte

s.Receive(Buffer)

Dim strDataReceived As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Buffer)

ProcessData(strDataReceived) 'Process data received...........

End while
```

When testing both server.exe-client.exe in local, the software work fine for several hours without any problem.

But when i start to run the server.exe in my real server, the connection between server-client usually become lost each other when client connected after a few dozen minutes. The symptom is client send packet to server but server does not receive the packet from client when server is still standing in 'sck.receive(Buffer)' command. I have tested many times but i still have no lucky to keep the connection run over 1 hour.

I have investigated about this problem but it still very strange :

- The server did not installed any firewall software.
- The client did not using any proxy and antivirus, firewall software
- I using a bandwidth logging software on server to make sure the internet in my server is stable.
- I make a 'ping -t' from my client computer to the server and keep looking on it to sure there are no connection lost between client and server . The ping command indicate that the ping time is usually range from 5ms to 50ms and no connection time out occur.
- Even I try to unplug the network cable in the client computer for a few seconds, and then replug again to simulation the disconnect event. I've awesome that my connection between server-client is still maintain and it's not the problem that cause my symptom.

I was thinking to write a code for auto reconnect if received timeout. But it could make my software usually delay when reconnecting if the above symptom still there. I really want to know what wrong with my code and which is the solution for me to fix the above symptom?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of why it's breaking over a real, live connection (maybe something about the socket going idle and closing) perhaps someone who knows more about TCP than I do can answer that. However, do you really want to keep a connection idle for that long of a time? In most implementations I've seen, software that wants to keep the socket open for that long without receiving data sends a keep alive packet every so often to make sure that the socket stays alive.

Oh and make sure that you are a) flushing the stream (if it's buffered) and b) not hitting the nagle effect

Comment: I've found that it's usually the ISP that disconnects long running TCP connections. If I were the OP, I'd write the server to listen for incoming connections without a while loop. And when the client sends a message, it does a "connect - send - disconnect" for sending the messages. Reading the messages can be different routine where the client is setup to listen as well instead of a while loop. When the client connects the first time, the server keeps it as a "this is an open connection" even after disconnect, to know to send the client a message when there's one to send.

Comment: I agree with a keealive packet. But he isn't hitting the nagle algorithm when talking about dozens of minutes. That algorithm doesn't work like that. The buffering/delay is done within the TCP stack, and is also relevant at high transfer rate, not across many minutes. The stack will flush the packet on its own within some number of milliseconds. You don't have to flush a TCP socket if it is setup correctly. Actually you can't flush it on most OS. Maybe by toggling TCP_NODELAY, as I've read on Linux. If anything, nagle just hurts performance.

Comment: I'm not sure the nagle algorithm is relevant here - that's more to do with combining short packets to reduce the overhead of packet headers. More likely it's just a connection timeout because there's not been any traffic.

Comment: Yeah I apologize for the mis-information. Nagle only works in short time periods when you do write write read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely the server is behind some sort of firewall (Cisco ASA, etc.) which has idle connection timeouts. When you "punch" through a firewall / NAT device, a "session" is created within the firewall kernel. There is an associated resource that has to be reclaimed, so firewalls do not usually allow unlimited connection timeout, but firewalls do support things like dead connection detection.

Adding a keepalive packet / activity every 5 minutes, or disconnecting / reconnecting is the only way around that. Few network admins are going to change their configs to accomodate this.  It is pretty simple to implement a "ping" or "keepalive" command in custom TCP application protocols. Just send the string and consume it, you don't even have to respond to the packet to accomplish resetting the idle timer within the firewall, though that would probably be best practice.

**When I say keepalive, I don't mean the TCP keepalive socket option. That is a zero-length packet, and is detectable by a good firewall, like Cisco.** Cisco admins can setup rules to quietly deny your keepalive packet, so the solution is to implement it above the TCP layer, in the Application layer, by sending a small string of data like "KEEPALIVE\r\n".

Comment: As i mentioned, i do not install any firewall in the server. All software in the server is setup by me since Window installed so i know exactly no firewall installed.

Comment: So your client and server are on the same physical network? I didn't say "the server" had the firewall. I meant the firewall is between the client and server. Unless they are on the same network, you probably are going through a firewall and don't know it.

Comment: The client is also my home computer (which also using my home network) so i know that there is no firewall on it. I also running other software like Yahoo, Skype in my computer which are type of long connection software and it still very stable.

Comment: The server is running in Datacenter

Comment: That is my point. You already said it yourself:  "But when i start to run the server.exe in my real server, the connection between server-client usually become lost"

Comment: I just set the KeepAlive packet by the below code
---
sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, True)
SetKeepAlive(sck, 500000, 300000) ' 5 minute = 300000 milliseconds
---
But the disconnect sympton still occur. Are you have a sample working code for Keep-Alive method ?

Comment: The problem with using the standard TCP keepalive is that the keepalive packet provided by TCP is a zero-length packet, and firewalls can actually detect it. Many admins actually install rules to drop idle sessions. I've had similar issues before with keepalive not really working, and the solution was to send some actual data.

Comment: Oh my god, you safe my life. The software running to now is over 2 hour and no problem occur. I don't know what to say. THANK YOU SO MUCH!